# rpart not creating Decision Tree in R, SVM works

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, decision-tree

I'm trying to create a decision tree for classification but it doesn't get created. The same data performs with 0.85 accuracy using a SVM (train == test data), "play" is the target...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here is the data and code:
https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/c471819cbf156a69f73daf49f8c700c6

> outlook,temp,humidity,windy,play
>
> sunny,hot,high,false,no
>
> sunny,hot,high,true,no
>
> overcast,hot,high,false,yes
>
> rainy,mild,high,false,yes
>
> rainy,cool,normal,false,yes
>
> rainy,cool,normal,true,no
>
> overcast,cool,normal,true,yes
>
> sunny,mild,high,false,no
>
> sunny,cool,normal,false,yes
>
> rainy,mild,normal,false,yes
>
> sunny,mild,normal,true,yes
>
> overcast,mild,high,true,yes
>
> overcast,hot,normal,false,yes
>
> rainy,mild,high,true,no

For using the SVM I've encoded the data:
https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/9bfce4182eda3d7662315621462c9cc6

> outlook,temp,humidity,windy,play
>
> 1,1,2,FALSE,FALSE
>
> 1,1,2,TRUE,FALSE
>
> 2,1,2,FALSE,TRUE
>
> 3,2,2,FALSE,TRUE
>
> 3,3,1,FALSE,TRUE
>
> 3,3,1,TRUE,FALSE
>
> 2,3,1,TRUE,TRUE
>
> 1,2,2,FALSE,FALSE
>
> 1,3,1,FALSE,TRUE
>
> 3,2,1,FALSE,TRUE
>
> 1,2,1,TRUE,TRUE
>
> 2,2,2,TRUE,TRUE
>
> 2,1,1,FALSE,TRUE
>
> 3,2,2,TRUE,FALSE

This is the SVM case:

```
library(e1071)
df= read.csv("5.tennis_encoded.csv")
attach(df)
x <- subset(df, select=-play)
y <- play
detach(df)
model = svm(x,y,type = "C")
pred = predict(model,x)
truthVector = pred == y
good = length(truthVector[truthVector==TRUE])
bad = length(truthVector[truthVector==FALSE])
good/(good+bad)
```

[1] 0.8571429

And this one for the Decision Tree

```
df= read.csv("5.tennis_encoded.csv")
library(rpart)
model = rpart(play ~ .,method = "class", data=df)
print(model)
```

1) root 14 5 TRUE (0.3571429 0.6428571) *

So I basically get a tree with only a root and 0.64% probability for play == yes

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are passing to the algorithm too few data for splitting.

Check the rpart.control function for more details

```
rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = round(minsplit/3), cp = 0.01, 
              maxcompete = 4, maxsurrogate = 5, usesurrogate = 2, xval = 10,
              surrogatestyle = 0, maxdepth = 30, ...)
```

As you see, the minimum split size is 20.

If you

```
model = rpart(play ~ .,method = "class", data=df, control= rpart.control(minsplit=2))
```

You should get more splits